# How to map XML to a class/dataset when elements/attributes are known, but don't occur everytime?

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

For a C# project I'm querying an API, which returns me an XML similar to this:

```
<itemlist>
  <item attrib1="Value1" attrib2="Value2"... attrib15="Value15">
    <sometypeinfo1 attrib1="Value1" attrib2="Value2"... attrib15="Value15">
      <subelement>
        <someproperty attrib1="Value1" attrib2="Value2"/>
        <someproperty attrib1="Value1" attrib2="Value2"/>
        <someproperty attrib1="Value1" attrib2="Value2"/>
      </subelement>
    </sometypeinfo1>
    <sometypeinfo2>
      <subelement attrib1="Value1" attrib2="Value2">
        <someproperty>
          <somedescription attrib1="Value1" attrib2="Value2"/>
          <somedescription attrib1="Value1" attrib2="Value2"/>
        </someproperty>
      </subelement>
    </sometypeinfo2>
    <sometypeinfo3 attrib1="Value1" attrib2="Value2"/>
    <sometypeinfo4>
      <someproperty attrib1="Value1" attrib2="Value2"/>
    </sometypeinfo4>
    <sometypeinfo5>
      <someproperty attrib="somevalue"/>
    </sometypeinfo5>
    <somemodifiers>
      <somemodifier attrib1="Value1" attrib2="Value2"/>
      <somemodifier attrib1="Value1" attrib2="Value2"/>
      <somemodifier attrib1="Value1" attrib2="Value2"/>
    </somemodifiers>
    <someflags>
      <someflag attrib="somevalue"/>
      <someflag attrib="somevalue"/>
      <someflag attrib="somevalue"/>
    </someflags>
  </item>
  <item>
  .
  .
  .
  </item>
</itemlist>
```

Its basically a list with ~ 100  items/file and every one with alot of descriptions, attributes etc.
Now, thats not something unusual.
I have trouble mapping it into a class or dataset. For example this line

```
<sometypeinfo1 attrib1="Value1" attrib2="Value2"... attrib15="Value15">
```

One item may miss attrib1, another attrib2, a 3rd one may have all 15 etc.

Same with "Someflags", there can be one item with 5 "someflag"s, the next one only with 2.
etc.
Every element or attribut CAN be there, but doesnt has to. So they all share a pool of elements/attribs, and this is where I get stuck with serialization etc.

Yes, I'm new to this. But from what I've learned so far, a schema has to have all elements/attribs to have the XML being mapped properly?

The only thing that comes to mind would be writing another tool that collects all possible elements etc., then writing a class that contains all, NULL everything in the first place and then just parse the XML, overwriting everything found in the actual item.

Comment: Either you will declare classes containing all of the attributes and tags -as you say- to deserialize to a concrete class, or parse manually(using for ex. Linq2xml) to get the desired data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most XML parsing tools represent the attributes of an element as a collection, and you can iterate over that collection.

they also represent child elements as a collection too.

Here's some sample syntax using my XML parsing class of choice, but c# has multiple build in options that you can explore at your leisure.

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("myXML.xml");
        XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//sometypeinfo1");

        foreach (XmlAttribute a in node.Attributes)
        {
            Console.Write(a.Name);
            Console.Write(a.Value);
        }
```

[here's a further documentation on XPATH that i used here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

We encountered a similar problem and used an XSLT style sheet to transform the attributes of the original XML into elements in a new XML document (load the XSLT into an XslTransform object to transform the original XML).  The new XML document was then read into a DataSet object.

See the msdn articles:
[Inferring DataSet Relational Structure from XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b4194wc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
and 
[Inferring Relationships](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecb1hddt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Partial XSLT example to transform your XML above from attributes to elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/itemlist"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="itemlist">
        <xsl:element name="itemlist">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:element name="item">
            <xsl:element name="attrib1">
                <xsl:value-of select="@attrib1"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="attrib2">
                <xsl:value-of select="@attrib2"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="attrib3">
                <xsl:value-of select="@attrib3"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <!-- continue above pattern for all 15 attributes. -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="sometypeinfo1"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="sometypeinfo1">
        <xsl:element name="sometypeinfo1">
            <xsl:element name="attrib1">
                <xsl:value-of select="@attrib1"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="attrib2">
                <xsl:value-of select="@attrib2"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="attrib3">
                <xsl:value-of select="@attrib3"/>
            </xsl:element>
                <!-- continue above pattern for all 15 attributes. -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="subelement"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="subelement">...
```